# Scaled canvas pixelated bug on Safari

Tags: css, safari, html5-canvas, css-transforms, image-rendering

I need to scale up and transform a canvas and it works great with the following CSS property on Chrome for example:

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

But on Safari (macOS and iOS), it remains blurry.

I made a small codepen to check the issue: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/Kalane/pen/RwYoXYw)

Here is a screenshot of the wanted result on Chrome: [image: Chrome result]
And here is the bug on Safari on my Mac: [image: Safari result]

Thanks a lot if someone has an idea! I have the feeling I tried almost everything but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the `will-change: transform;` property that I applied on the canvas.

I still don't know why but if I remove it, it's not blurry on Safari anymore...

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution! In my case, I wasn't using `will-change`, but I was using a `transform` to scale the canvas. When I switched it to using width/height to scale instead, it worked perfectly.